# Overflow-y changes the color of the text

Tags: html, css

I am learning HTML and CSS and I have the following issue, I have a long list of items and I am applying overflow-y with external CSS. The problem is that it changes the font color of the list. I would also be grateful for any info on how to style the scrollbar and only be visible when scrolling.

```css
#main-div {
position: relative;
}
#container-div {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
margin-top: 15%;
margin-right: 10%;
overflow-y: auto;
width: 600px;
height: 350px;
}
.main-text {
color: aliceblue;
mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-div">
<div id="container-div">
<div id="list" class="main-text">
<h4>title 1</h4>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
<h4>title 2</h4>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
<h4>title 3</h4>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
<h4>title 4</h4>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
<h4>title 5</h4>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
<h4>title 6</h4>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please provide code or make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You need to include some code along with your question. Please review the link MaxiGui has provided to give others a reproducible example that can be worked with.

Comment: What do you mean it changes the font-color ? What exactly is causing that ?

Comment: @Adarsh I think the mix-blend-mode doesn't work when the text overflows and the whole text goes to aliceblue. I have a background image on the whole page, and when I comment out the overflow-y property, mix-blend-mode works fine, but not when overflow comes into play.

Comment: In your code you have mix-blend-mode for the "main-text" class. I don't see it being used anywhere.

Comment: My bad, the #list has class="main-text" as well, will edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just made it with the wrong class.

since you set the `height` on the `container-div`, you should use your `mix-blend-mode` on the same one.

Try this:

```css
#main-div {
position: relative;
}
#container-div {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
margin-top: 15%;
margin-right: 10%;
overflow-y: auto;
width: 300px;
height: 150px;
background-color: #e2e2e2;
color: aliceblue;
mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-div">
  <div id="container-div">
    <div id="list">
      <h4>title 1</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
      </ul>
      <h4>title 2</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
      </ul>
      <h4>title 3</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
      </ul>
      <h4>title 4</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
      </ul>
      <h4>title 5</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
      </ul>
      <h4>title 6</h4>
      <ul>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
        <li>item 1</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've added a background to see the aliceblue color

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the font-color changing. But to style the scrollbar, check the css snippet below.

```css
#main-div {
position: relative;
}
#container-div {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
margin: 10%;
overflow-y: auto;
width: 600px;
height: 300px;
background: lightblue;
}

/* Styling Scroll Bar */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1; 
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #c1c1c1; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555; 
}
```

```html
<div id="main-div">
<div id="container-div">
<div id="list">
<h4>title 1</h4>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
<h4>title 2</h4>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
<h4>title 3</h4>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
<h4>title 4</h4>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
<h4>title 5</h4>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
<h4>title 6</h4>
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 1</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```